# How to modify error messages in jsf?

Tags: jsf

I am using primefaces4, jsf2.0 and tomcat6 for my application.
I am using `<p:clientValidator event="blur">`. I need to modify the error message for example "Number: Validation Error: Value is required." It is coming on blur if the field is empty but i want to modify that to "Number is required." where "Number" is the label of the field. I have tried this in my resource bundle file "javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED={0} is Required" but still its showing the old message "javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED={0} is Required". Plz help me where should i modify the message.

Sorry if any mistakes, am a new bee in jsf.
Thanks in advance

Comment: *"my resource bundle file"* where exactly is this file located and how exactly did you register it? The symptoms namely indicate that you did that part wrong (i.e. not according the instructions found in the average JSF book/tutorial/answer).

Comment: its located in src folder and i registered that in faces-config as below.                                                              <application>  <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
     <locale-config>
 <default-locale>en</default-locale>
     </locale-config>
 <message-bundle>ApplicationResource</message-bundle>
 <resource-bundle>
    <base-name>ApplicationResource</base-name>
    <var>msg</var>
 </resource-bundle>
</application>

Answer (score 0):

1) Create your version of **validation.properties** file (rename it as you want)

2) Add line `javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED={0} is Required` in this file.

3) Register your properties file in **faces-config.xml**:

```
<application>
    <message-bundle>your.path.here.validation</message-bundle>
</application>
```

For more info see link [Customize validation error message in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: I did the same as u said but its not working ,if i use <rich:validator> then in onblur ots showing the edited message from the properties file ,but i need the same with <p:clientValidator>

Comment: `message-bundle` contains path, in your case it is `<message-bundle>validation</message-bundle>`. Try it. Sorry, I am using RichFaces, but it should work in any faces.

Comment: its located in src folder and i registered that in faces-config as below. <application> <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELReso‌​lver</el-resolver> <locale-config> <default-locale>en</default-locale> </locale-config> <message-bundle>ApplicationResource</message-bundle> <resource-bundle> <base-name>ApplicationResource</base-name> <var>msg</var> </resource-bundle> </application>

Comment: Change your registration in faces-config (see step 3 in answer)